# C++ token handler

Tags: c++, function, callback, reference

I have an application where I have GUI layer and functional layer. Function pump some information to GUI. To communicate well, I am registering some signals with a call back in GUI class. The problem is I have hundreds of signals and handlers. The code is same but only the type and param is changing. I wish to reduce the number of lines of code. The present implementation is something like below

```
                               /* HEADER FILE */
```

//member variables

```
SignalSharedPtr signalptr1; //signalSharedPtr is a custom shared pointer I derived
SignalSharedPtr signalptr2; 
SignalSharedPtr signalptr2; 
.................
.................
SignalSharedPtr signalptr100;


SubscriptionToken tkn_signalptr1;
SubscriptionToken tkn_signalptr2;
SubscriptionToken tkn_signalptr3;
SubscriptionToken tkn_signalptr4;
.................
.................
SubscriptionToken tkn_signalptr100;


//Member functions 
void functionHandler1(parameter)
void functionHandler2(parameter)
void functionHandler3(parameter)
.................
.................
void functionHandler100(parameter)







                               /* SOURCE FILE */ 

//In constructor, I will register the DD signals to the handlers
readsignalptr1()
readsignalptr2()
readsignalptr3()
readsignalptr4()
................
................
................
readsignalptr99()
readsignalptr100()



tkn_signalptr1 = signalptr1->addModifiedNotificationHandler(bind(&className::functionHandler1,     this, (dataType*)signalptr1.get()));
......................
.......................
tkn_signalptr100 = signalptr1->addModifiedNotificationHandler(bind(&className::functionHandler100, this, (dataType*)signalptr100.get()));
```

//I am looking for a mechanism to write a common function which will receive signal name, reference to the function so if I have a utility class, I wish to call something like this

```
registerCallBack(signal1,this_class, functionHandler1);
registerCallBack(signal2,this_class, functionHandler1);
......
......
registerCallBack(signal100,this_class, functionHandler100);
```

So the function body I wish to write only once.

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. You may get what you want with a `std::map(Signal, std::function<void(parameter)>> signalmap` to map a `Signal` object to the function to be run. Then you can `signalmap.at(signal)(parameter);`

Comment: I am happy to explain what is unclear.

Comment: Unfortunately if I knew what to ask to get you to clear it up, I would have asked.

Comment: Right now I am repeatedly adding the handlers. It's structure is same. I want to write a common function, which receives a signal, a callback function. So I could simply call this function with signal name and member callback function. I got lot of errors when I tried couple of examples

Comment: Perhaps it will be clearer if you show one of these attempts. Who knows, someone might even be able to tell you what went wrong. Your goal of `registerCallBack(signal1,this_class, functionHandler1);` seems, on the surface, perfectly reasonable. One thing I can think of that'll screw it up is if you try to stuff pointers to member functions into a function pointer expecting a free function, something I don't expect if you're using `bind`

Comment: Side note on `bind`: Often a lambda expression works better.

Comment: I am using bind at the moment

Comment: Apologies for wording that comment poorly. It is because you are using `bind` that I expect you have avoided the problem I described.

Comment: if (signal)
 {
  tkn_Signal = signal- >addModifiedNotificationHandler(bind(&cmyClass:onSignal, this, (DataObjectInt*)signal.get()));
 }

Comment: I wish to use the above line of code only once in a function by passing signal and onSignal like member functions. Without using bind, I don't know what are the alternatives

Comment: Tried as per the first comment. Std::map creation. It returns C2664

Comment: map<MySharedPtrInt, std::function<void(myInt*)>> signalMap;
 signalMap[signal]= onMySignal((myInt*)signal.get());
This gives me binary = no operator takes right hand operand of type void (C2679) error :-(